# Instantiate abstract class but then re-declare with specific derived class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have a base class with pure virtual functions and two different derived class from this base class.
For the purposes of scoping I need to instantiate abstract class then choose which derived class needs to be used in the program. Note that I am passing the myObj by reference.

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual int build(const std::string &fname) = 0; //pure virtual build function
}

class A : public Base {
    public:
        int build(const std::string &fname); //Implementation of build
}

class B : public Base {
    public:
        int build(const std::string &fname); //Implementation of build
}

int run(const Base &myObj) {
       //Random things will be done based on myObj being passed by reference
       //myObj.get_info();
       //myObj.val;
}

int main(const char *tag) {
    
    std::string s = tag;
    Base myObj;
    if(s.compare("Class A")) {
        A myObj;
    }
    if(s.compare("Class B")) {
        B myObj;
    }
    run(myObj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You talk about `get_info()` and `.val` in your comments, but I don't see either of those. You also declare `build` virtual and talk about "abstract" classes, but you don't use pointers or polymorphism anywhere. Can you elaborate on what the goal is here?

Comment: My goal is that I will at the end of my coding have about 10 other derived classes.  But each derived class will have a `.val` and `get_info()` which will be used in run.  But which derived class that needs to be built will depend on the `tag` coming into the main.  The reason I do not have pointers right now is because I have a working code with one derived class and everything implemented within `run` (which I did not include) passes `myObj` by reference.  So when I tried pointers I could not get it to compile because all my functions are taking `&myObj`

Comment: Your problem isn't about instantiating an abstract class. It is about setting up logic to instantiate different derived classes depending on a string. Declare `myObj` as a pointer to `Base`, and then when `s.compare("Class A")` tests true do `myObj = new A`, when `s.compare("Class B")` tests true do `myObj = new B`, etc.  Release the object when done. You can make it cleaner using a smart pointer, but I'll leave that as an exercise. BTW:  you need to actually read up on how to do things in C++.  Guesswork like you are doing (or assuming C++ works like another language you know) doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done, at least as you specified. In C++, when working with inheritance like this, you'll usually need to use heap-allocated objects.

I'd recommend using a `std::unique_ptr` for this purpose, for example:

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<Base> myObj;
    if (s == "Class A") {
        myObj = std::make_unique<A>();
    }
    else if (s == "Class B") {
        myObj = std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    else {
        // Handle the case where `s` is another string - otherwise below
        // you'll get undefined behavior (bad!) when trying to dereference
    }
    run(*myObj);
```

Note that I fixed some of the syntax errors you had in your question, but it seems like you're trying to use C++ as if it was some other language :)

Comment: Yeah C++ is not my normal language and I know you can't instantiate an abstract class, but it is the essence of the problem I was encountering.